# Git checkout - exclude tags/remotes from possibilities list?

Tags: git

If I use `git checkout` and hit tab to show the list of possibilities, I am faced with an ever increasing list (we tag all releases).

```
$ git co 
Display all 183 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Is it possible to exclude tags and/or branches on the origin from the list it displays? Ideally, I'd prefer to only show my local branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git checkout refs/heads/<TAB>`, this will only complete your local branches.

Comment: It's also a good idea to do `git fetch -p` every now and then to get rid of the branches that no longer exist on the remote (According to the manual: *-p, --prune After fetching, remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.*)